# C# - Get method from inherited class

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm working on a monogame project that uses gamestates, and I'm in the process of refactoring.

I've got state classes which inherits abstract methods from the parent class state.cs,
for example MainGameState : State.

In every individual state class I've got repeating code, I'm trying to bundle that into my state.cs class, but I can't seem to call it with State.MethodName.

I'm sure I missed something obvious but I need a hand, thanks in advance

code below

State.cs

```
public abstract class State 
{
    /*
        [Description]
        Abstract class for menu state methods to be used in GameWorld.
    */

    private bool isInitialized;


    private bool isMenu = true;

    public bool IsMenu { get => isMenu; set => isMenu = value; }
    
    public abstract void Initialize();
    public abstract void LoadContent();
    public abstract void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch);
    public abstract void Update(GameTime gameTime);

    public void InitializeCheck()
    {
        // checking if Initialize() has run if it has then skip
        if (!isInitialized)
        {
            Initialize();
        }
    }


}
```

example of the call I want to make

MainGameState.cs

```
public class MainGameState : State
{

  public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        State.InitializeCheck();
    }



}
```

Comment: You don't need to do `State. InitializeCheck();`. Just call the method with `InitializeCheck();`..

Answer (score 1):

[@Chetan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72483697/c-sharp-get-method-from-inherited-class/72483814#comment128044546_72483697) solved it:

> You don't need to do `State InitializeCheck();`. Just call the method with `InitializeCheck();`.